# How to switch from continuous to discrete formulation (integral to sum) in a specific case?

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, summation, riemann-sum

in the paper "Economic conditions and the popularity of parties: a survey" Kirchgaessner (1986) transforms a utility function from continuous to discrete. I get the intuition and the meaning, I just do not get, where the (1-lambda) in front of the sum in [2.4] comes from, when transforming the integral [2.3] to a sum [2.4]. Can anyone help? I attached a picture of both equations. There are no further steps given in the paper.

Formulas in tex:

```
GP(t_{l}) = GP(0)exp(-\mu t_{l}) + \int_{0}^{l}g(F(x(t),t))exp(\mu (t-t_{l})) dt  \ \  [2.3] \newline

GP_{l} = GP_{0} \lambda^{l} + (1-\lambda) \sum_{t=1}^{l}(g(f(x_{t}),t))\lambda^{l-t} \ \ [2.4] \newline

\lambda := exp(-\mu)
```

[continous function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqo6g.png)

[transformed to discrete function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3nXR.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: okay, is there a way to inculde a tex code?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).